# Migrating Low-Values in flat file to RDB

Tags: rdbms, cobol

I have an indexed file where a particular field now holds alphanumeric values and this field is a part of the Key, that particular column has LOW-VALUES in a rows and SPACES in another row, these two rows are identified as unique fields in indexed file, but when I try to migrate this to a RDB I get unique key violation since LOW-VALUES in RDB is treated as spaces. has anyone faced a similar instance and how did you handle it?

Note: Right now, I'm just planning to replace LOW_VALUE with "*RANDOM*" text. I just want to know is there any other possibility to handle LOW-VALUE in RDB.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit odd that a record key would contain either spaces or low-values. Strikes me that you may be migrating some "bad data".

However, if these are valid values, then you need to replace one of them: Low-values (probably binary zeros) or spaces with something else that will not conflict with any currently existing or likely to exist value for that key.

Keys on one file are often held as references in other files - you will need to track down and convert all of these as well. Failing to do so will lead to a corrupted database (broken RI constraints etc).

This does not look like a "pretty" situation.